# How to search for text across multiple rows in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, rows

So I'm quite new to Python, and I was just wondering if it is possible for me to use it in order to search for text across multiple rows. Here is a screenshot of my dataframe:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeqpv.png

To make it clearer, what I would like to do is search for phrases or expressions containing more than one word, such as 'New Jersey,' however, each word makes up a separate row so I do not know how to go about including more than one row in the query. I would also, if possible, like to create a new column which will label any matches with 'M' and those without 'N.' All help is appreciated to make this easier for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to join all rows to be able to search multiple continuous words.

For example, we want to find the phrase "she wants to" in whole dataframe:

```py
>>> df
   subtitle
0       She  # <- start here (1)
1     wants  #
2        to  # <- end here (1)
3      sing
4       she  # <- start here (2)
5     wants  #
6        to  # <- end here (2)
7       act
8       she  # <- start here (3)
9     wants  # 
10       to  # <- end here (3)
11    dance
```

```py
import re

search = "she wants to"
text = " ".join(df["subtitle"])

# index of start / end position of the word in text
end = df["subtitle"].apply(len).cumsum() + pd.RangeIndex(len(df))
start = end.shift(fill_value=-1) + 1

# create additional columns
df["start"] = start.tolist()
df["end"] = end.tolist()
df["match"] = False

# find all iteration of the search text
for match in re.finditer(search, text, re.IGNORECASE):
    idx1 = df[df["start"] == match.start()].index[0]
    idx2 = df[df["end"] == match.end()].index[0]
    df.loc[idx1:idx2, "match"] = True
```

```
>>> df
   subtitle  start  end  match
0       She      0    3   True
1     wants      4    9   True
2        to     10   12   True
3      sing     13   17  False
4       she     18   21   True
5     wants     22   27   True
6        to     28   30   True
7       act     31   34  False
8       she     35   38   True
9     wants     39   44   True
10       to     45   47   True
11    dance     48   53  False
```

**Update**: search for multiple terms:

Change only:

```
# search = "she wants to"
search = ["she wants to", "if you", "I will"]
search = fr"({'|'.join(search)})"
```

```
# df = pd.DataFrame({'subtitle': ['She', 'wants', 'to', 'sing', 'she', 'wants', 'to', 'act', 'she', 'wants', 'to', 'dance', 'If', 'you', 'sing', 'I', 'will', 'smile', 'if', 'you', 'laugh', 'I', 'will', 'smile', 'if', 'you', 'love', 'I', 'will', 'smile']})
>>> df
   subtitle  start  end  match
0       She      0    3   True
1     wants      4    9   True
2        to     10   12   True
3      sing     13   17  False
4       she     18   21   True
5     wants     22   27   True
6        to     28   30   True
7       act     31   34  False
8       she     35   38   True
9     wants     39   44   True
10       to     45   47   True
11    dance     48   53  False
12       If     54   56   True
13      you     57   60   True
14     sing     61   65  False
15        I     66   67   True
16     will     68   72   True
17    smile     73   78  False
18       if     79   81   True
19      you     82   85   True
20    laugh     86   91  False
21        I     92   93   True
22     will     94   98   True
23    smile     99  104  False
24       if    105  107   True
25      you    108  111   True
26     love    112  116  False
27        I    117  118   True
28     will    119  123   True
29    smile    124  129  False
```

**Update 2**: terms into text file:

```sh
$ cat terms.txt
she wants to
if you
I will
```

```
search = [term.strip() for term in open("terms.txt").readlines()]
search = fr"({'|'.join(search)})"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I get an error message, however, saying 'NameError: name 'it' is not defined.'

Comment: Fixed it. I forgot the enumerate in the loop! Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is the closest I've gotten to what I want. But, rather than creating a separate dataframe, is there a way to create a new column in the original dataframe that can mark any matches with 'M,' and non matches with 'N'?

Comment: @Regan I updated my solution. I preferred use a boolean column rather than values 'M' and 'N'.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need. Sorry to be annoying, but I just have one more query, how would I go about searching for multiple terms?

Comment: Sadly I don't have enough reputation points :(

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again, I swear this is the last thing! I have quite a lot of search terms, so is there anyway for me to incorporate them into a txt file? I've tried doing it myself but I'm getting the error 'IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0' after the for loop.

Comment: Thanks again! I still get the ' IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0' though :(

Comment: Open a new question with your actual code (no image, use `print(df)`) and post here the url. I (or someone else) will try to answer it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769502/how-to-search-for-multiple-search-terms-across-multiple-rows-in-a-pandas-datafra