# How to search for multiple search terms across multiple rows in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, search

So my previous, more simplified question is here - [How to search for text across multiple rows in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647189/how-to-search-for-text-across-multiple-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe/67648549?noredirect=1#comment119774718_67648549)

What I want to do is basically to be able to feed a text document containing multiple phrases, not just singular words, i.e. 'new jersey,' etc, into a search and then to search for the terms across multiple rows and output a new column in the table with 'True,' if the terms and present and 'False,' if not. For instance, this is a very small section of my table, and I would like to search 'new jersey' and 'grew up,' with words that are in separate rows.

```
             subtitle        start          end  duration
14                new    71.986000    72.096000  0.110000
15             jersey    72.106000    72.616000  0.510000
16               grew    72.696000    73.006000  0.310000
17                 up    73.007000    73.147000  0.140000
18          believing    73.156000    73.716000  0.560000
```

So far, thanks to kind help on the old thread, this is what I have, with terms.txt being the list of search terms:

```
import re

search = [term.strip() for term in open("terms.txt").readlines()]
search = fr"({'|'.join(search)})"
text = " ".join(df["subtitle"])
end = df["subtitle"].apply(len).cumsum() + pd.RangeIndex(len(df))
start = end.shift(fill_value=-1) + 1
df["start"] = start.tolist()
df["end"] = end.tolist()
df["match"] = False
```

Everything works fine up until this point:

```
for match in re.finditer(search, text, re.IGNORECASE):
    idx1 = df[df["start"] == match.start()].index[0]
    idx2 = df[df["end"] == match.end()].index[0]
    df.loc[idx1:idx2, "match"] = True
```

I get the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9f347152f616> in <module>
      1 for match in re.finditer(search, text, re.IGNORECASE):
----> 2     idx1 = df[df["start"] == match.start()].index[0]
      3     idx2 = df[df["end"] == match.end()].index[0]
      4     df.loc[idx1:idx2, "match"] = True

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   4099         if is_scalar(key):
   4100             key = com.cast_scalar_indexer(key, warn_float=True)
-> 4101             return getitem(key)
   4102 
   4103         if isinstance(key, slice):

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this or if there are other methods I could use to acheive the desired result? All help is appreciated, and I apologise for any formatting issues since I am very new here.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 columns 'start' and 'end'.

```
import re

terms = [term.strip() for term in open("terms.txt").readlines()]
word = df["subtitle"].str.strip()
end = word.apply(len).cumsum() + pd.RangeIndex(len(df))
start = end.shift(fill_value=-1) + 1
text = " ".join(word)
df["match"] = False
```

```
for term in terms:
    for match in re.finditer(fr"\b{term}\b", text, re.IGNORECASE):
        idx1 = start[start == match.start()].index[0]
        idx2 = end[end == match.end()].index[0]
        df[idx1:idx2] = True
```

Output:

```
$ cat terms.txt
new jersey
hello

>>> df
   id   subtitle   start     end  duration  match
0  14        new  71.986  72.096      0.11   True
1  15     jersey  72.106  72.616      0.51   True
2  16       grew  72.696  73.006      0.31  False
3  17         up  73.007  73.147      0.14  False
4  18  believing  73.156  73.716      0.56  False
```

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful, but unfortunately I am still getting the same error as above!

Comment: Did you test this code on your example only or your dataset? What is your version of Python and Pandas? Maybe you should share your excel file.

Comment: I tried just on this data. How do I share my Excel file exactly? Sorry I'm really new here! To add, it's also a JSON file that I am really working with.

Comment: Edit: Could the issue occur if some of the search terms do not fit the exact wording/criteria present in the table?

Comment: No I already tried non existing term and return an empty dataframe without raising error.

Comment: You can use https://filebin.net/ to share your code, your excel file, your term file and a screenshot of your error, I'll try to debug.

Comment: filebin was not working for me, so I've used DropBox. Since I am not really working with an Excel file also, as I have thousands of columns, I have included only a small chunk. Everything else is labelled accordingly. Link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/tww36mpeihopggh/AADSdqeQaNxGp5wM6Ze0vrBSa?dl=0

Comment: Edit: maybe the issue occurs if there is more than one instance of the search term?

Comment: I fixed it. It worked for your example. Keep me informed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This does work, but the 'true' value prints into other columns, not just the 'match.' Please could you also re-share the very first solution you made on my old post, wherein, instead of there being a match column in the same table, a new table is generated with the matches? I would like to remember how to do this too, if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: Edit: actually, it does not work, I get this output, so the true/false is not accurate because the 'true' is transferring to other columns, and 'boy meets girl' isn't matched.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qawacaxbz61ocw/Screenshot%202021-06-07%20at%2013.03.31.png?dl=0

Comment: Please check https://gist.github.com/corralien/895da1b65ecf89eee7e753dc01ded889

Comment: There are no error messages, but, for some reason, this does not print a true/false column or a separate table with the matches?